# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly

Tags: .net

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

e.g. `{"name":"value"}` into type

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[domvc.Models.EMP]
```

because the type requires a `JSON` array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Please add sample json format + EMP class details so in question

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. The problem is the array definition for the JSON to process.

After creating the main data class `Routine`, create the object to get the list

```
public class RoutineList
{
    public List<Routine> routines { get; set; }
}
```

then read the JSON and deserialize like

```
RoutineList rtns = new RoutineList();
rtns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoutineList>(result);
```

The JSON knows the de-serialized data corresponds to a list of `Routines`, in this case. This fixed the error for me.